# What is the use of node.js in the development of Angular 4 project?

Tags: node.js, angular

I have worked on AngularJS, I have to work on Angular 4, What is the use of Node.js and NPM in Angular 4 project development? Can any one explain?

Comment: Some reading: https://angular.io/guide/npm-packages

Comment: Angular is a front-end javascript framework which operates in the clients web browser. Node is a service which can execute javascript and is often used on a server maybe in replacement of PHP (like in MEAN stack).